# HikariCP - linkage Error using HikariDataSource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss, hikaricp

I have a Linkage Error when i start JBOSS AS 6.1 with a `HikariDataSource`. How to solve this?

I use hikariCP 1.3.3:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
     <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.3</version>
  </dependency>
```

Spring 3.2, JBOSS AS 6.1, Hibernate 3.6.6 (bundled with JBOSS). I removed persistence.xml and confgiure my DataSource programatically using `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` approach from: http://www.baeldung.com/2011/12/13/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-3-1-and-jpa/

My DS i configured simply:

```
   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
      HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(); //here i get the linkageError
      ds.setMaximumPoolSize(15);
      ds.setDataSourceClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource");
      ds.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", "localhost");
      ds.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", "dbtest");
      ds.addDataSourceProperty("user", "dbtest");
      ds.addDataSourceProperty("password", "dbtest");
      ds.setPoolName("springHikariCp");
      return ds;
   }
```

And the end of stacktrace is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource com.company.test.PersistenceJPAConfig.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181) [:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570) [:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 135 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.<clinit>(HikariConfig.java:77) [:]
    at com.company.test.PersistenceJPAConfig.dataSource(PersistenceJPAConfig.java:115) [:]
    at com.company.test.PersistenceJPAConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2cad8762.CGLIB$dataSource$3(<generated>) [:]
    at com.company.test.PersistenceJPAConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2cad8762$$FastClassByCGLIB$$7a8bcfa3.invoke(<generated>) [:]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:285) [:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.company.test.PersistenceJPAConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2cad8762.dataSource(<generated>) [:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [:1.7.0_11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160) [:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 136 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/zaxxer/hikari/proxy/ProxyFactory"
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.JavassistProxyFactory.<clinit>(JavassistProxyFactory.java:58) [:]
    ... 148 more
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/zaxxer/hikari/proxy/ProxyFactory"
    at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1099) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at javassist.CtClass.toClass(CtClass.java:1265) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.JavassistProxyFactory.modifyProxyFactory(JavassistProxyFactory.java:131) [:]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.JavassistProxyFactory.<clinit>(JavassistProxyFactory.java:54) [:]
    ... 148 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/zaxxer/hikari/proxy/ProxyFactory"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) [:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634) [:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor131.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [:1.7.0_11]
    at javassist.ClassPool.toClass2(ClassPool.java:1112) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1093) [:6.1.0.Final]
    ... 151 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On JBOSS AS 6.1 the solution to this problem was for me putting HikariCP-1.3.5.jar \server\app\lib and in pom.xml set it as `provided`. When i migrated the application to WildFly 8 Hikari works as `compile`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two things.  First, I suggest upgrading HikariCP to the latest version, 1.3.5.

Second, the error appears to be classloader related, the exception `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` indicates that the static class initialization for `HikariConfig` is being executed twice somehow.  This should only be possible if there are two classloaders referencing the same HikariCP jar.  Ensure that the HikariCP jar is not located in the global library directory for JBoss, but is instead located in the container library directory of the application.  If there are multiple application containers, the HikariCP jar should be located in each of them individually.

Comment: Upgraded to 1.3.5 and verified that the HikariCP-1.3.5.jar was only in the .war in \WEB-INF\lib, but that didnt fixed the error. When i set Hikari to `provided` and put it into \server\app\lib it works.

Comment: I get the same error using version 2.0.1 with Tomcat 7.0.23.

Comment: Is the HikariCP jar in two locations in your deployment?  For example, the Tomcat lib folder as well as the webapp folder?  Seems most likely.

Comment: Same here issue with HikariCP 2.2.5 on Tomcat 7.0.22, JDK 1.70_22, Linux 2.6; and it's a clean installation: I'm quite sure there's NOT another Hikari jar elsewhere...

Comment: @GiorgioVespucci can you open a bug over on the HikariCP project page? Given that some users have gotten it working, I'm still not convinced its not a configuration error.  Also, please post your stacktrace in the bug; even if similar the line-numbers are likely slightly different.

Comment: @brettw https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/217 Done, thank you. :)